# Save date to file in json format using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to save the current date in the following format to a file and wrap it in a simple json body, so far I was thinking of something like this:

```
jsonTimeStamp=`$({"timestamp":"$(date +%FT%T.%3N%Z)"})`; > deps/image-details.json
```

zsh: command not found: timestamp:2020-10-16T10:36:49.3NEDT

this gives me the following error:

> command not found: timestamp:2020-10-16T10:38:38.3NEDT

I am out of ideas, can someone please point to what's going wrong here?

Comment: What is you desired output? I'm not sure why you have $( before the timestamp string

Comment: @RamanSailopal I was trying to save that into a variable to use down the line, if it's not needed I can leave it off

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "{\"timestamp\": \"$(date +%FT%T)\"}" > my.json
```

Comment: `printf` would be a better choice here: `printf '{"timestamp":"%s"}' "$(date +%FT%T)" > my.json`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
jq -cn '{"timestamp":(now|todateiso8601)}' >deps/image-details.json
```

or

```sh
jq -cn '{"timestamp":(now|todate)}' >deps/image-details.json
```

or

```sh
jq -cn '{"timestamp":(now|strftime("%FT%T"))}' >deps/image-details.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You could let `date` itself output the JSON:

```sh
date '+{"timestamp":"%FT%T.%3N%Z"}'
```

```
{"timestamp":"2020-10-16T15:00:11.214EDT"}
```

---

Have a close look at what you're doing in your question. I'm going to replace the semicolon with a newline:

```sh
jsonTimeStamp=`$({"timestamp":"$(date +%FT%T.%3N%Z)"})`
> deps/image-details.json
```

You set the variable on the first line, and on the second line *you truncate the output file to zero bytes*.

Comment: Since Bash 4.3+, built-in `printf` has a special  `%(fmt)T` time formatter: `printf '{"timestamp":"%(%FT%T%z)T"}\n'`